# modifying code in java

Tags: java, sorting

So i've written some fairly standard sorting algorithms for sorting an array of strings. I wanted to modify some of the sorting methods so they sort the data slightly differently. Here is what i wanted to do:

Selection Sort currently runs through the remaining part of the array, looking for the minimum value and then swaps it to the front. I want to change the algorithm so that it also looks for the maximum value in the remaining part, and swaps it to the back, so that it builds up a sorted list from the front and the back at the same time.

Insertion sort currently inserts each item into the sorted region that it is building up from the left. It does this by searching down the sorted region, one item at a time. I wanted to use binary search on that region to find the right place to insert the item.

This is the code i have so far:

```
/** Swaps the specified elements of an array.
 *  Used in several of the sorting algorithms
 */
private  void swap(String[ ] data, int here, int there){
    String temp = data[here];
    data[here] = data[there];
    data[there] = temp;
}

/* ===============SELECTION SORT================= */

/** Sorts the elements of an array of String using selection sort */
public  void selectionSort(String[ ] data){
    // for each position, from 0 up, find the next smallest item 
    // and swap it into place
    for (int place=0; place<data.length-1; place++){
        int minIndex = place;
        for (int sweep=place+1; sweep<data.length; sweep++){
            if (data[sweep].compareTo(data[minIndex]) < 0)
                minIndex=sweep;
        }
        swap(data, place, minIndex);
    }
}

/* ===============INSERTION SORT================= */
/** Sorts the  elements of an array of String using insertion sort */
public  void insertionSort(String[] data){
    // for each item, from 0, insert into place in the sorted region (0..i-1)
    for (int i=1; i<data.length; i++){
        String item = data[i];
        int place = i;
        while (place > 0  &&  item.compareTo(data[place-1]) < 0){
            data[place] = data[place-1];       // move up
            place--;
        }
        data[place]= item;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would use use Array.binarySearch to find the place to insert. I would also use Arrays.sort() to sort the array.